# Фильтрация картинок в cke editor 4

Tags: html, cms

Как с помощью фильтров, вытаскивать ВСЕ картинки из тега

и если они идут подряд то заворачивать их в другой тег с определенным классом.

Например, что бы было

```html
<p>text</p>
<p><img1></img1></p>
<p><img2></img2></p>
<p><img3>text</img3></p>
```

и это преобразовалось на выходе в

```html
<p>text</p>
<div class="imgs">
    <img1></img1>
    <img2></img2>
    <img3></img3>
</div>
<p><img2></img2></p>
<p><img3>text</img3></p>
```